# ¿Como puedo hacer para que funcione el intercambio de cadena caracteres?

Tags: c, string

El programa tiene que tener dos arrays de cadenas de caracteres, dos nombres, cada uno en su propia variable y luego intercambiar el contenido de los arrays.

Necesito que se intercambien el contenido de los arrays entre si.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#define TAM 20
int main(){ 
char a[TAM],b[TAM],c[TAM];

printf("NOMBRES Y ARRAYS\n");

printf("\nDigita un nombre\n");
gets(a);
strcpy(a,b);

printf("Digita otro nombre\n");
gets(c);
strcpy(c,a);
printf("\n%s",b,a);

getch();
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Redacta una función de intercambio de valores:

```
void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char aux = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = aux;
}
```

Y después intercambia cada una de las letras en la cadena:

```
for (int i = 0; i != TAM; ++i)
    swap(&a[i], &b[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

La función strcpy(arrayDestino,arrayFuente) como puedes ver tiene dos argumentos, el primero osea el arrayDestino, es el array que va a recibir el contenido del segundo argumento que es arrayFuente, eso es lo que hace strcpy(), sin embargo funciona siempre y cuando ambos argumentos tienen el caracter especial llamado fin de cadena el cual es '\0' (contra barra y cero) ubicado justamente al final de la cadena. sin ese caracter strcpy() no sabe donde termina la cadena de caracteres produciéndose un resultado inesperado, por esa razón, siempre que debas manipular un array tipo char con funciones de la librería string.h tal como strcpy() utiliza scanf() en lugar de gets() para la captura de caracteres, porque este ultimo no añade el fin de cadena sino que añade un salto de linea '\n', no así scanf() que si añade el fin de cadena.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAM 20

int main(){ 
    char nombre1[TAM], nombre2[TAM], auxiliar[TAM];

    printf("NOMBRES Y ARRAYS\n");

    printf("\nDigita un nombre\n");
    scanf("%s",nombre1);
    printf("- nombre1: %s\n",nombre1);

    printf("\nDigita otro nombre\n");
    scanf("%s",nombre2);
    printf("- nombre2: %s\n",nombre2);

    strcpy(auxiliar,nombre1); //salvaguardamos en 'auxiliar' el nombre que contiene 'nombre1'
    strcpy(nombre1,nombre2); //ahora 'nombre1' recibe el nombre contenido en 'nombre2' 
    strcpy(nombre2,auxiliar); //y 'nombre2' recibe el contenido de 'nombre1' que fue salvaguardado en 'auxiliar' completandose asi el intercambio

    printf("\nIntercambio\n");
    printf("nombre1: %s\n",nombre1);
    printf("nombre2: %s",nombre2);

    return 0;
}
```